# Using nested iif statements to subtract two columns of data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Working in Visual Studio 2012 to create a SSRS Business Intelligence Services Report.

Trying to do something like below where based on the value of one column, subtract the value of another column.

```
=iif(Fields!ACADEMIC_YEAR.Value=Parameters!ACADEMIC_YEAR.Value, Fields!TotalProspects_Dom.Value-iif(Fields!ACADEMIC_YEAR.Value=Parameters!ACADEMIC_YEAR.Value-1,Fields!TotalProspects_Dom.Value, 0),0)
```

Basically my table looks like:
[image: Visual Studio Table Screencap]

essentially the table for the report is two rows, the current academic year and the previous academic year and I have to compare the two. Each row is made of columns representing the data for domestic and international data for a larger group.

Comment: What exactly isn't working about it?

Comment: It only returns the value of the inner iff statement as a negative.

What I need is:
Value of Outer IIF - Value of Inner IIF. I thought a nested IIF statement would solve that, but I'm thinking now that there may be a better solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to have separate IIFs to determine the year.

```
= SUM(IIF(Fields!ACADEMIC_YEAR.Value = Parameters!ACADEMIC_YEAR.Value, Fields!TotalProspects_Dom.Value, 0) 
- SUM(IIF(Fields!ACADEMIC_YEAR.Value = Parameters!ACADEMIC_YEAR.Value - 1, Fields!TotalProspects_Dom.Value, 0)
```

Comment: This worked, Thanks so much :) I wish I could vote this as a correct answer, I just don't have the reputation to do it

Comment: If above answer helped you, you can marked it as a correct answer by clicking on the "correct" symbol at left of answer. 
[How to accept an answer ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)